# How does an AB Weird Science recreate their Trapping items if lost/destroyed?

Tags: savage-worlds, savage-worlds-adventure-edition

How does an AB Weird Science recreate their Trapping items if they are lost or destroyed?

P.148 says they must always use their item ... *A weird scientist’s Trappings (see page 150) must always include the item they’re associated with.*

Then the example on p.149 in Jury Rigging shows them being able to use a power, albeit at the -2, after the item is lost ... *Gabe is captured by evil aliens and all his equipment is taken. He’s placed in a holding cell and decides he’ll use the overhead lights and whatever the aliens use for electricity to create a makeshift blast.*

But how does Gabe ever recreate his item?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the Adventure Edition? My Core book does not have either of the quotes you present.

Comment: @Szega Both the quotes and the page references are right out of the shiny and new Adventure Edition. The question even has an Adventure Edition tag.

Comment: @Szega The extracts were direct from v5.2 of SWADE, which I believe is the version going to the printers.

Answer (score 3):

Replacing the gizmo is automatic, between adventures.

This isn't explicitly stated, unlike previous version of Savage Worlds. Unfortunately. But the character has taken an Edge that grants these gizmos and they should refresh during downtime - like replacing a Trademark Weapon, a Soldier adapting to new gear loads, or finding a replacement Beast Master companion.

For a group that doesn't have "time between adventures" you'll need to find something that works for your unique gaming environment, but I'd recommend one full day's work per gizmo being replaced.

Another good option is to pull from the Arcane Devices rules, page 153. One hour per Power the gizmo can generate.